# Mapping address to US map with only hospital name using R

Tags: r, google-maps, data-visualization

I have list hospitals names with state details, but no zipcode or longitude/latitude information to create a U.S map visualization. Is there any alternative way to map those hospitals to a map using R or online tool?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is essentially asking us to do your searching for you. You need an external resource of some sort to translate names to location.

Comment: Take a look at the ggmap package.  There are functions to geocode lat/long data from location names.

Comment: the [googleway package](https://github.com/SymbolixAU/googleway) will also geocode addresses using Google's API